# Face tracking software on mac (in build camera)

Tags: macos, opencv, camera

I want a way to track a user looking at a screen over time.

E.g. in normal use what exact seconds of the day had the user looking at the screen.

I'm wondering what innovative ideas or pre-existing software would allow me to do this.

So for more detail the way I see it is there would be some tolerance levels e.g. distance from screen, angle of head to screen that would be considered "engaged" with the monitor. If the camera on say a mac book pro was used to track this then it would record in a text file/key value store a timestamp and boolean value for each second of the time the program in turned on.

Anyone any experience with this sort of thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find a good starting point here: http://code.google.com/p/ehci/

It's a software based on OpenCV that tracks head and detect its orientation. It's opensource.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not appear to be ready for mac. Certainly could have a go at getting to work on iOS but ideally I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: but it does look to record exactly what I need.

Comment: You can look into code for what you need. It's code is a bit confusing (a sort of Frankenstein software) but should work with iOS with a little work.

Answer (score 3):

There are facetrackers implemented (and already trained with markers), for example in OpenCV. I suggest you to first start with just tracking faces. Once you have a robust facetracker, and you can generate output telling how long a face has been looking at the screen, etc.

Later you can add improvements. Once you detect a face, you can try to recognize people analizing face pixels.

Another line is to recognize parts of the face, like mouth, eyes, nose, eyebrows...

If you can track face and parts of the face, you can try to recognize facial expression patterns, like happines, sadness, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Face.com has a solution to regonize faces. So just grab the camera input and send it to their servers I guess?

Comment: Seems to suggest it only accepts photos as opposed to video. Now I do realize video is just a sequence of photos but looks like might be a lot of work to strip that out with time and send to there API to get results.

Answer (score 1):

I've built a face detection system to do something like this once using OpenCV, you can see the result [here](https://studiodiip.com/).

The method I used then was two seperate uses of haarTraining with the standard built in OpenCV  classifiers. I used the classifier called haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml to see if a user is watching the screen and haarcascade_profileface.xml to see if the user was looking away. The following code should get you started using openCV and C++.

```
CvHaarClassifierCascade *cascade_face;
CvMemStorage            *storage_face;
CvHaarClassifierCascade *cascade_profile;
CvMemStorage            *storage_profile;

//profile face
storage_profile = cvCreateMemStorage( 0 );
cascade_profile = ( CvHaarClassifierCascade* )cvLoad( "haarcascade_profileface.xml", 0, 0, 0 );
cvHaarDetectObjects( frm, cascade_profile, storage_profile, 1.1, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);

//frontal face
storage_face = cvCreateMemStorage( 0 );
cascade_face = ( CvHaarClassifierCascade* )cvLoad( "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml", 0, 0, 0 );
cvHaarDetectObjects( frm, cascade_face, storage_face, 1.1, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);

//detect profiles
CvSeq *profile = cvHaarDetectObjects(img,cascade_profile, storage_profile, 1.1,3,0,cvSize( 20, 20 ));

for( i = 0 ; i < ( profile ? profile->total : 0 ) ; i++ ) {
    CvRect *r = ( CvRect* )cvGetSeqElem( profile, i );
    //draw rectangle here, or do other stuff
}

//detect front
CvSeq *faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(img,cascade_face, storage_face, 1.1,3,0,cvSize( 20,20 ));

for( i = 0 ; i < ( faces ? faces->total : 0 ) ; i++ ) {
    CvRect *r = ( CvRect* )cvGetSeqElem( faces, i );
    //draw rectangle here, or do other stuff
}
```